# How to get browser's current page URL from iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, iframe

Ok. This might have been asked several times but my problem is slightly different. I have following page tab in my facebook application:

[Facebook Page Tab](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Hammad-Rasheed/137291572958477?id=137291572958477&sk=app_691079004271485)

This facebook page tab has my website embedded as iframe into it. What I want is that is to get the URL of current page inside my application.

For example, if you open above link you see facebook URL in your browser(obviously) address bar. In my iframe I just want to retrieve the URL of the parent page in which it is embedded.

I know same-origin policies in Javascript don't allow playing with cross-domain parent page's markup using javascript but I just want to retrieve the parent page URL, thats it.

Is that possible in ANY way?
Any way to access the address bar URL in my PHP application?

Thanks.

Comment: You probably don’t need the “actual URL”, but only the page id, I assume …? That you can get by decoding the `signed_request` parameter that gets POSTed to your app on initial load into the iframe.

Comment: Yes, I need only the page ID, on the basis of that page ID I need to show the specific user's products in my application. Any example to show how do I decode this parameter in my application?

Comment: Add my comment as an answer, plus link that describes how to decode the signed request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don’t need the “actual URL”, but only the page id, I assume …? That you can get by decoding the `signed_request` parameter that gets POSTed to your app on initial load into the iframe.

How to “decode” it is described here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games#parsingsr

If you’re using the PHP SDK, that has a method already that does this for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Correct me if I am wrong, from what I have we can only get the signed request when the user is logged in or we implement OAuth. In my case I can't do that.

Comment: Let me tell you how my application will work. Any user on facebook (logged_in or logged_out) can access any page who has my application installed on his page. Then on that facebook page who has installed my application, I need to show products belonging to the page owner only.

Comment: I wanted that somehow I could get the page_id in that page tab so that I could decide which user's products to show on that page.

Comment: No, the user does not have to be logged in to your app, nor do you have to implement OAuth – you will get a `signed_request` posted to your app on initial load into the iframe anyway – it will just not contain specific user information when there is no logged in user; but it will contain the page info regardless.

Comment: Hmmm...Seems like I am close to solving it..Thank you. +1 for you already.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**You can use this to access it in JavaScript:**

```
top.location.href
```

`"top"` is better than `"parent"`. Because if your iframe is itself in another iframe then parent will return that iframe's location. `"top"` will return the highest location.

Comment: Open your browsers console and type top.location.href in it as a test. It will work. I added an image as proof :)

Comment: It could have worked had I owned facebook. :)
You are writing the code at facebook's page console, not my application's console. :)
Any other suggestion would be highly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Ah I see now. Your iframe is serving content from another domain. Then the SOP applies and you can't get out of it unfortunately. You could use CORS (Cross-origin resource sharing) but this requires the higher domain to allow your domain (or all domains) which is unlikely :(

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and insight. I am giving you +1 for that. I got to find some way to do that.

Comment: I just had an idea!!! You can use the http referrer field to see the domain requesting your page :)

Comment: The referrer is `https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy/hv09mZVdEP8.js` in this case. Doesn't help

Comment: I have just tried it and it is not even printing the URL you showed. It is showing the iframe src...

Comment: In Chrome console, you have to select the inner frame first (upper left pulldown arrow) instead of the outer html page

Comment: Yes I tried to get referrer using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'].

Comment: it should be $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; REFERER is a misspelling of REFERRER that was never corrected :) One of the many interesting things about internet standards :)

Comment: Just a typo here. I actually used REFERER, checked my code again.

Comment: That would mean that it's not set, which makes it more difficult. I can't think of another way atm... :(

Comment: Typically, browsers don’t send a referrer when HTTPS is used … and browsing via HTTPS is standard now for using facebook.com (And even if that wasn’t the case, the referrer should not be used for such purposes anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

This will be a tough one, because CORS forbids to access the outside frame:

[image]

The referrer doesn't help very much either.

If you want to use the `signed_request`, and want to send custom data/parameters to your app, have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs#integrating

You can then fill the `app_data` parameter, and decode that in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any way to hack it?

Answer (score -1):

Try one of these:

```
parent.document.location

parent.window.document.location

parent.window.location

parent.document.location.href
```

I'm not sure if this will work on facebook though

Comment: Tried that earlier, they all print my application's document